# Tag synonym of Store for Shop

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, shop

Can a tag synonym be created for [store](/questions/tagged/store) of [shop](/questions/tagged/shop)? I know I'm the only person who tagged this, but I imagine it could be a commonly recurring thing... Especially since the website for the store is http://shop.stackexchange.com (http://store.stackexchange.com redirects to it)

**Edit**
I had it the wrong way round!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[shop](/questions/tagged/shop) is the correct tag, and [store](/questions/tagged/store) is now a synonym.